# MVC Repository pattern and UOW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am working on project with MVC Repository Pattern. I have created a generic repository for CRUD operation. My questions are:-

1. Do I need to create a separate UOW class for each entity or Should I create generic repository object in controller. (Both are working)
2. In case if I have an entity/table that are fetching and updating based on foreign key instead of Primary key what should I do in that case. (I think in that need to create normal repository class)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer on **first question**: ***it depends***.

- If your UoW just wrap repository object and do nothing else, you
  should not add this (UoW) abstraction to your code.
- Else, if you have some special code that should be executed before saving and is not database code (something like domain validation or other), you should add UoW and put this code in it.

**Second question** seems that you set wrong column as Primary Key. May be your Foreign Key column should be also PrimaryKey?

Comment: Quite convincing answer, if I exclude UoW and directly create object of Generic Repository in Controller, where I will use IDisposable interface. All the articles that I have read on internet either they use IDisposable interface in normal repository or in UoW class .. Any Idea

Comment: You can use it in Repository (wrap in using construction creation of dbcontext) or you can dispose repository in dispose method of controller.